# Retrieving multiple mongo documents from cursor.next() for better performance

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following code to gather arrays (stored as pickled documents in a Mongo collection) and stack them into a 2D numpy matrix:

```
db = MongoClient()['db']
total = db.command('collStats', 'collection')['count']
collection = db['collection']

X, Y = np.array([]), np.array([])
pipe = [{'$sample': {'size': total}}]
cursor = collection.aggregate(pipe, allowDiskUse=True)

for i in range(1000):
    try:
        xy = pickle.loads(cursor.next()['array'])
        if not np.size(X):
            X, Y = xy[0:-1], xy[-1]
        else:
            X, Y = np.vstack((X, xy[0:-1])), np.vstack((Y, xy[-1]))
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

which is extremely slow. How can I optimize this, say, to read multiple documents at once from Mongo? Any other optimization tips would be useful as well

Comment: Did you profile your code to see where it spends most of his time? Why are you using `range` here?

Comment: Why do you need to run the "collStats" command? Also there is some performance issue with `$sample`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @SSDMS, I am using `range` to loop through the random sample and stack 1000 documents, returned as arrays, to a 2D matrix. I'm running the `collstats` command to know the total number of documents in the collection. Basically I want to be able to access random documents in the collection. It's ultimately for feeding training examples into a neural  network. What are the performance issues with `$sample`, and how can I get around them while still doing what I want?

Comment: You can use `collection.count()` to get the number of document in the collection. Now, why are you passing that number to `$sample` if you only need 1000 documents? why not `{'$sample': {'size': 1000}}`? You didn't answer my first question. Did you *profile* your code? I can see that you are only interested in the "array" field in each document. How about `$project`ing your document to return only that field?

Comment: @SSDMS I need to be able to iterate through every single document in the collection, but I need them to be sampled in a random order from the collection. And _yes_, I did profile my code. The majority of the time is spent stacking the arrays - about 50x as much time as is spent reading in the documents. I wanted to know if there was any way to read in a chunk of the sampled documents (which are list) and have them vertically stacked as a 2D numpy array - which would be essentially the same as a list of documents (lists) converted to an ndarray - and do so sequentially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way I found to improve performance:

1. Convert each item to a list
2. Append that list to a list of lists
3. Convert to a 2D numpy array

So, for my case, like this:

```
xy = pickle.loads(curosor.next()['array']).tolist()
X, Y = [xy[0:-1]], [[xy[-1]]]

for i in range(1000):
    try:
        xy = pickle.loads(cursor.next()['array']).tolist()
    except StopIteration:
        break
    X.append(xy[0:-1])
    Y.append([xy[-1]])

X, Y = np.array(X), np.array(Y)
```

Improved my performance by a factor of 50.

Answer (score -1):

There is a `cursor.toArray()` that returns everything at once.